# Render Anchor by using Glassmapper in sitecore mvc

Tags: model-view-controller, hyperlink, sitecore, anchor, glass-mapper

I am facing problem for rendering the anchor by using the glass mapper in sitecore mvc.

This is the code I have used to render the link:

```
@RenderLink(promoWidget, x => promoWidget.Link, new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection { { "target", promoWidget.Link.Target },{"class",promoWidget.Link.Class}}, true, contents: promoWidget.Link.Text)
```

But when from sitecore we select the link and click on insert anchor I put the text and anchor text. When I display this link by using above code it will render link this:

```
<a href="product#product" class="link">product</a>
```

It is showing 2 times `product#product`. I want to display only once `#product`.

How can I do this?

Appreciate the help

Thanks,
Amol

Comment: sorry I missed the anchor tag <a href="product#product" class="link">product</a>

Comment: What is the value of your "promoWidget.Link" in Sitecore?

Comment: In the sitecore , there is general link  field is  there  there we are clicking on Insert Anchor and we are giving value of Text=  Product and Anchor= Product. and by using @Renderlink we displaying the link

Comment: Are you seeing this behavior in page editor or when previewing/viewing live version?  I duplicated your test and saw that page editor was duplicating my link.text, but the href was right.  When viewing preview version, it rendered correctly.

Comment: @CraigTaylor I am seeing this behaviour in live version. I don't know how it is rendering twice . please can u help me on this ASAP.

Comment: Try changing the text and anchor text to distinct values. (producta and productb, respectively)  This will help give us clues to what piece of content is being duplicated.

Comment: @CraigTaylor Hi, It will replace Anchor text. like if we give anchor text as ProductDetail then href is replaced by ProductDetail#ProductDetail.